# WinForms Migration from .NET 4.x to .NET 5 - How do I remove AspNetCore dependencies from project?

Tags: winforms, .net-5

I recently used the new preview .NET Upgrade Assistant to migrate a .NET Framework 4.8 WinForms project to .NET 5. I've worked through the code to resolve incompatibilities, but I'm running into an error I can't figure out when I try to build the app.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4096 The item "C:\TFSRoot\SEImportDatabase\SE Import Database 5.0\DataCleansing\obj\x64\Debug\net5.0-windows\apphost.exe" in item list "ContentWithTargetPath" does not define a value for metadata "TargetPath".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ContentWithTargetPath.TargetPath), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.   DataCleansing   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets 203
```

The referenced section in the targets file is:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_WebRootFiles Include="@(ContentWithTargetPath)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(TargetPath)').Replace('\','/').StartsWith('wwwroot/'))" />
  <_ReferencedStaticWebAssets Include="@(StaticWebAsset)" Condition="'%(SourceType)' != ''" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I'm also seeing the following AspNetCore dependencies that I don't understand since this is a WinForms app, not an ASP.NET Core app:

```
Dependencies>Analyzers>Microsoft.AspNetCore.Analyzers
Dependencies>Analyzers>Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Analyzers
Dependencies>Analyzers>Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers
Dependencies>Frameworks>Microsoft.AspNetCore.app
```

I assume that the Frameworks dependency is leading to the error above, but I don't know why it's there or how to remove it.

How do I remove these dependencies from my WinForms project? Or is there something else to look for that would be causing this error?

Here's a screenshot of my Dependencies:

[image: Dependencies]

EDIT: Here's my csproj content, as requested.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <!--<Import Project="..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props')" />-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>SE Import Data Cleansing Application</AssemblyName>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>{data here}</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
    <ManifestKeyFile>DataCleansing_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <PublishUrl>\\lifeaction.net\dfs\download\Life Action\SE Import Database Core\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Unc</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <TargetCulture>en-US</TargetCulture>
    <ProductName>SE Import Data Cleansing Application (Core)</ProductName>
    <PublisherName>Life Action Ministries</PublisherName>
    <CreateWebPageOnPublish>false</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
    <WebPage>publish.htm</WebPage>
    <OpenBrowserOnPublish>false</OpenBrowserOnPublish>
    <ApplicationRevision>734</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>File import.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <UserSecretsId>{data here}</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="LifeAction.Common.Utilities">
      <HintPath>\\lifeaction.net\dfs\download\.NET Libraries\LifeAction.Common.Utilities\LifeAction.Common.Utilities.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="LifeAction.SmartyStreets, Version=1.0.5490.16347, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>\\lifeaction.net\dfs\download\Life Action\SmartyStreets\LifeAction.SmartyStreets.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="System.Core">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Update="System.Xml.Linq">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="DataGridView2.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <!--<Content Include="appsettings.json" />-->
    <!--<Content Include="Splash.png" />-->
    <None Update="App.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
    </None>
    <None Update="App.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
    </None>
    <!--<Content Include="NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    </Content>-->
    <None Update="NLog.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>NLog.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
    </None>
    <None Update="NLog.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>NLog.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>true</IsTransformFile>
    </None>
    <None Update="NLog.xsd">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Update="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!--<ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 2.0 %28x86%29</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.0 %28x86%29</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>-->
  <!--<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="File import.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PublishFile Include="Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <Group>
      </Group>
      <TargetPath>
      </TargetPath>
      <PublishState>Exclude</PublishState>
      <IncludeHash>True</IncludeHash>
      <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
    </PublishFile>
    <PublishFile Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <Group>
      </Group>
      <TargetPath>
      </TargetPath>
      <PublishState>Exclude</PublishState>
      <IncludeHash>True</IncludeHash>
      <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
    </PublishFile>
    <PublishFile Include="Win32">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <Group>
      </Group>
      <TargetPath>
      </TargetPath>
      <PublishState>Exclude</PublishState>
      <IncludeHash>True</IncludeHash>
      <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
    </PublishFile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataCleansing.BLL\DataCleansing.BLL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataCleansing.Common\DataCleansing.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataCleansing.DAL\DataCleansing.DAL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataCleansing.DTO\DataCleansing.DTO.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataCleansing.Interfaces\DataCleansing.Interfaces.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataCleansing.Plugins\DataCleansing.Plugins.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataCleansing.SE.API\DataCleansing.SE.API.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="McMaster.NETCore.Plugins" Version="1.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DateTime" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah" Version="3.2.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Config" Version="4.7.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers" Version="0.2.212405">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!--<ItemGroup>
    -->
  <!--<Compile Remove="frmAddressValidation.cs" />-->
  <!--
    -->
  <!--<Compile Remove="frmAddressValidation.Designer.cs" />-->
  <!--
    -->
  <!--<Compile Remove="frmMediaOutlets.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="frmMediaOutlets.Designer.cs" />-->
  <!--
    <Compile Remove="frmAddressValidation.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="frmAddressValidation.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="InputBoxDialog.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="frmAddressValidation.resx" />
    -->
  <!--<Compile Remove="LayerFactory.cs" />-->
  <!--
    -->
  <!--<EmbeddedResource Remove="frmAddressValidation.resx" />-->
  <!--
    -->
  <!--<EmbeddedResource Remove="frmMediaOutlets.resx" />-->
  <!--
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="InputBoxDialog.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="DataCleansing.csproj.vspscc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!--<Import Project="..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets')" />-->
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.2.26\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.2.26\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Please share content of your csproj file as well.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've added it to my post.

Comment: The upgrade assistant is rather experimental, so not a surprise it makes several strange spots in the project file (like `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`). You'd better consider manual migration instead.

Comment: The first thing to fix: Change the sdk to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Well, so obvious if it'd been a snake it would have bit me. :-) I looked everywhere in the csproj file except that line. It builds correctly now!If you'll post that as an answer, I'll select it!

Comment: For .NET 5 use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong SDK.

The right [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) for Windows Forms Projects is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop`; however, starting in .NET 5.0, WinForms projects should specify the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` instead of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` like this:

- Set the sdk to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`
- Set the target framework to `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`
- Set the `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`

It also works using `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`; but, according to [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
Setting `TargetFramework` to `net5.0-windows` and setting `UseWindowsForms` to `true` will automatically import the Windows desktop SDK.  If your project targets .NET 5.0 or later and specifies the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK, you'll get build warning NETSDK1137.

Comment: You already have set `TargetFramework` and `UseWindowsForms`. Just apply the first bullet point. The second and third are just for sake of a complete answer for future readers.